# how to send multiple values of same select box by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

I have a `select` box with multiple select option. I want to send selected values in an array through an AJAX request. How can I select multiple values in the `select` tag and send all values in an array on click?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<select name="name[]" id="name[]">
  <option>--Select--</option>
  <?php $sql = mysql_query("select * from med_list order by medicine asc");
  while($sha=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
    <option style="color:#007F55" value="<?php echo $sha['id']; ?>">
      <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($sha['medicine']); ?>
    </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var bac = $("#bacteria").val();
  alert(bac);
});
```

Comment: Firstly, that `select` is not `multiple` so you'll only ever have a single value from it. Secondly, where's your AJAX logic?

Comment: `select name="name[]" id="name[]">` should be `select name="name" id="name" multiple>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: @Sandy the `select` *in the question* has no `multiple` attribute on it. Secondly don't use W3Schools as a reference. They are often outdated and wrong. Use MDN

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, add multiple attribute in select tag and remove array brackets in id attribute.
Second thing, on submit button you've get the value of wrong select box id.

Replace **var bac = $("#bacteria").val();** to **var bac = $("#name").val();**

```
<select name="name[]" id="name" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">Select Any Value</option>
    <option value="name1">Name 1</option>
    <option value="name2">Name 2</option>
    <option value="name3">Name 3</option>
    <option value="name4">Name 4</option>
    <option value="name5">Name 5</option>
</select>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var bac = $("#name").val();
  alert(bac);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```
<select id="data" name="data" class="data" multiple="multiple">
<option value="100">foo</option>
<option value="101">bar</option>
<option value="102">bat</option>
<option value="103">baz</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
   $(".data").val(["100", "101"]);
```

Comment: vote up, because someone says select can only be use for sending only one value which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The first is to know that you will sending an array of data,
if you use  " var bac = $("#bacteria").val();" it will only take the first item and it will pass it..
To send multiple values of same select box by ajax, start by making an array then pass it 
This is how i did it and it worked

```
if( $('#bacteria :selected').length > 1){
     var bac = [];
     $('#bac :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
       bac[i] = $(selected).val();
     }); 
    } else {
       var bac = $("#bacteria").val();; 
     }
```

You can ignore the if statement depending on your php file

Answer (score 1):

Use `id="name"` instead of `id="name[]"`

```
<select name="name[]" id="name">
```